# php, var_export fails with float

Tags: php, floating-point

very simple. Consider this code:

```
var_export (11.2);
```

this returns with

```
11.199999999999999
```

with Php 5.6

**wtf?**

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Same core question, hardly a dupe imho though.  No mention of `var_export` or `serialize_precision` in the linked post.

Comment: @ficuscr That's hardly relevant. OP is clearly unaware on how floats are represented and printed out. (The "wtf" and silly tags are a dead giveaway). Nothing unique about var_export there.

Comment: @mario Roger.  I'll read up more on the topic. Thanks for responding.  Didn't notice the tags till you pointed them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments on the man page of php.net:

> Looks like since version 5.4.22 var_export uses the
> serialize_precision ini setting, rather than the precision one used
> for normal output of floating-point numbers. As a consequence since
> version 5.4.22 for example var_export(1.1) will output
> 1.1000000000000001 (17 is default precision value) and not 1.1 as before.

Good to know.  I too was not aware of this change.

> **[serialize_precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)**
>
> Available since PHP 4.3.2. Until PHP 5.3.5, the default value was 100.

So, we can get the behavior we were familiar with using: `ini_set('serialize_precision', 100)`;

### Warning

Be very careful when using ini_set(), as this may change behaviour of your code further down the line. A "safe" way would be to use something like this:

```
$storedValue = ini_get('serialize_precision');
ini_set('serialize_precision', 100);
// Your isolated code goes here e.g var_export($float);
ini_set('serialize_precision', $storedValue);
```

This ensures that changes further down/deeper in your code is not affected.

Generally, using ini_set() in your code should be considered dangerous, as
it can have severe side effects. Refactoring your code to function without the ini_set() is usually a better choice.